# Resulting position from initial position, bearing and distance

Tags: java, geolocation, coordinates

I have tried to implement the function from this [site](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

> φ2 = asin( sin(φ1)*cos(d/R) + cos(φ1)*sin(d/R)*cos(θ) )
>
> λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin(θ)*sin(d/R)*cos(φ1), cos(d/R)−sin(φ1)*sin(φ2))

```
//import static  java.lang.Math.*;      
public static LatLng fromBearingDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double brng, double d) {     
    double R = 6371.0;      
    double lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) + 
              Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
    double lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                     Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
    return new LatLng(lat2,lon2);   
}
```

The result from my function is: `0.0905,1.710` when it should be `53.188 0.133`with the call

```
fromBearingDistance(53.32055555555556f, 1.7297222222222224f,
        96.02166666666666f, 124.8f);
```

which is the same coords as the sample site.

What could be going on here? - The code is literally like for like. The only things I changed was the vars to doubles.

I used [this](http://www.onlineconversion.com/map_decimaldegrees.htm) site to convert from degrees to decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think part of the problem might be that your latitude, longitude and bearing values appear to be in degrees, while the formulas on the page you linked call for them to be in radians.  If you scroll down the page toward the bottom, the page author has actually provided javascript implementations of the calculations, as methods of a `LatLon` object representing a location.  Here is the method which seems to match what you are trying to do.  Notice the first thing he does before the calculation is convert everything to radians, and the last thing he does is convert back to degrees.

```
/**
 * Returns the destination point from this point having travelled the given distance
 * (in km) on the given initial bearing (bearing may vary before destination is reached)
 *
 *   see http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#LL
 *
 * @param   {Number} brng: Initial bearing in degrees
 * @param   {Number} dist: Distance in km
 * @returns {LatLon} Destination point
 */
LatLon.prototype.destinationPoint = function(brng, dist) 
{
  dist = typeof(dist)=='number' ? dist : typeof(dist)=='string' && dist.trim()!='' ? +dist : NaN;
  dist = dist/this._radius;  // convert dist to angular distance in radians
  brng = brng.toRad();  // 
  var lat1 = this._lat.toRad(), lon1 = this._lon.toRad();

  var lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(dist) + 
                        Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(dist)*Math.cos(brng) );
  var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(dist)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                               Math.cos(dist)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
  lon2 = (lon2+3*Math.PI) % (2*Math.PI) - Math.PI;  // normalise to -180..+180º

  return new LatLon(lat2.toDeg(), lon2.toDeg());
}
```

The `java.lang.Math` class has methods for converting back and forth from degrees to radians, so it should be pretty easy to retrofit your code with them.

Comment: Excellent thats working perfectly now. Also I think I calculated the actual data incorrectly!